# mysql - updates on a column for every record in table that has 28 million records

Tags: mysql

I have a table where there is a column that contains values like this - ["12"].  The table has 28 million records in it.  When I perform the below, it takes forever and eventually just errors out and I receive this message - "ERROR 1206 (HY000) at line 1: The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size"

This is the update statement:

```
update table set category_ids = REPLACE(REPLACE(category_ids,'"]',''),'["','');
```

Basically, just trying to remove the [" and "] from the values in that column.

Is there a more efficient/better way to do this?

Comment: You could try locking the whole table first.  Don't know if it will help. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/lock-tables.html

Comment: I also tried increasing innodb_buffer_pool_size which is what I found related to this error.  Didn't seem to help.

Comment: Restarted the server? After changing buffer pool to something huge like 2gb

Comment: One good question here could be "why other dbms can deal with this except mysql with innodb?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tested this but just guessing.

select *limited* rows for update, and then update.

```
select * from my_table where col like '[%]' limit 0, 100000 for update;
update my_table set col=replace(.... where ... limit 100000;
```

on the next iteration you can try like

```
select * from my_table where col like '[%]' limit 100001, 100000 for update;
update my_table set col=replace(.... where ... limit 100000;
```

This practice can control the number of locks permitted.

Comment: That's the solution.  It's still very slow, updating 1 million records per 1.75 hours, so this update will take the next 49 days to complete!

Comment: Just observed, the second limit boundary change in the `select ...` was wrong. It too should be `limil 0, 1000001